# reverse todonotes side without changing chapter number placement in classicthesis

Tags: classicthesis, todonotes

When using todonotes with classicthesis, my notes appear on the wrong side.
I have added the options \let\marginpar\oldmarginpar  and \reversemarginpar
to my preamble but when I use \reversemarginpar it also reverses the placement
of the classicthesis fancy chapter numbers.
Is there a way to reverse the side of todonotes only, without messing with the classicthesis formatting?

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{classicthesis} 
\usepackage{todonotes}
%\let\marginpar\oldmarginpar
%\reversemarginpar
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{a duck section}
\blindtext
\todo{a note} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems like a bug, please inform the author of `classicthesis`.

Comment: As this uses an `scr` class, you might be able to redefine `\@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine` to use a note column instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs because classicthesis is putting the chapter number in the marginpar, and so it is affected by \reversemarginpar.
You can work around it by specifying the *linedheaders* option to classicthesis.
The result is not quite the same, but you can always turn off that option when you no longer need todonotes.